# Will quote be removed after order created?

Tags: magento2, orders, quote

Currently when I look in database, the quote of order still exist after order successfully created. Will the order quote be removed later under some conditions? What happens to order if associated quote removed and vice versa?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the order is placed, the quote is deactivated. The field `is_active` is set to 0.
There is a cron that removes all the inactive quotes that are older than X days.
The cron is `sales_clean_quotes` and it maps to `Magento\Sales\Cron\CleanExpiredQuotes::execute()`.

> What happens to order if associated quote removed and vice versa?

Nothing. The order is valid if you remove the quote. And the quote will be cleaned up by the cron later if you remove the order associated to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer